# How useful and practical EF is in reality?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am old school and new to MVC. I like the MVC that's more focus on action. But MS has bundled it w/ EF together, it's hard to not to use EF nowadays.

This is what I thought:

1 - RDBMS stored proc/package suppose have better performance over LINQ. For instance, SQL Server Transact-SQL supports paging now, compared with LINQ, TSQL definitely has better performance. So LINQ is only good for people don't know TSQL or PL/SQL in terms of performance.

2 - I've tried using LINQ w/ stored proc. Thought it works but has many limitation, for instance, .dbml files are strongly-typed, it prohibited any attempts of re-formatting the data, such as adding an anchor to a field of display. Well, one might say you're not supposed to do so. Let me give an example, business wants to make a column clickable in a grid. There are a number of ways to implement, one of the quickest is to embed an anchorto the column returned from a stored proc, very little change on the UI. Hence QA just needs to test a few. But using EF as the foundation, anything based on this model/class must QA again.

3 - Model-first or Code-first wouldn't get a nice normalized large-scale database implementation, this is because if a developer doesn't know TSQL he wouldn't be good at RDBMS design.

4 - This is the most important issue: in an enterprise environment, we developers can NOT dictate schema and table definitions. Even with DB-first approach, sometimes we don't even know where it comes from. But that's what EF is good about, right? You might say. Imagine EF detects all schema and what returned from stored proc, then builds all data-layer/class for me. Great, but there is a need for a real-time median price which is not in the database at all, we add it in w/ some customization code. It will be gone if another scan and detect is needed because our client requests something causes a tiny change in the database. How do we avoid this hassle of losing customization code?

5 - Sometimes we need to run "update-database" command in the package console so EF can work. It's almost impossible to explain to Operation and DBA that they are harmless during release.

However, as EF is getting popular there must be a new-school way to make it work. Can some experts educate old-school please?

Comment: This isn't a good question for StackOverflow, but for #2, lookup projection, you can easily add new fields.  For #3, I wouldn't say that using EF means you wouldn't know about database design! #4 - We can dictate the design of the software. The DBA becomes a reviewer of changes and a mentor for the dev team.  #5 - You can use an EF feature which generates SQL scripts if you need to.

Comment: #4 - We can dictate the design of the software. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's true, it's not a good question for SO but I completely share you thougts. Besides I think EF is for people who have no idea about sql (I've met many like them). It's always easier to write and test a stored procedure than spend hours finding out why a particular linq query doesn't work and most times you'll have to get the sql it generated and execute it directly on the server... so what's the point of using it at all? Earlier to fix something you just could fix a stored procedure. Now you need build the whole app. Should you ask this question on Programmers etc. please leave a comment.

Comment: I think that this article on continuous delivery practices is probably worth a read: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/continuous-delivery-for-databases-microservices,-team-structures,-and-conways-law/

Comment: See the section on how the modern DBA (DBA-as-a-Service).  Most DBAs are not involved in development of software, but are developing reports after the development, or maintaining server estates.  The design of the software will generally affect the design of the database, e.g. adding new columns etc.  In the example of a median price, that could be tackled by calculating the median price once on each change, then caching it in redis across a server farm, reducing the cost of the SQL statements.  It's just a different approach.

Comment: If your linq query is uber complicated, there's nothing wrong with using a sproc, but why waste time writing the other 90% of basic SQL when the system can do that for us?  For my teams, a deploy is just a click of a button in the build server, so it's not a big deal to deploy to production. Also, we use mini profiler to display the executed SQL on each web page, useful for finding poorly performing EF code.